# Java EE - container managed authentication. FORM and Social

Tags: java, facebook, authentication, glassfish

I have an application running on GlassFish 4 in which Glassfish is managing the security and authentication through "FORM" Login Configuration.

My question is:

Is it possible to add an external/third party authentication method on top of this?

(Facebook in my case)

Would I have to ditch "j_security_check" and do everything programmatically?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.